# In g++ is C++ 11 thread model using pthreads in the background?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, pthreads

I am just trying my hands on `g++ 4.6` and `C++11` features.
Every time I compile a simple threading code using `-std=c++0x` flag, either it crashes with segmentation fault or it just throws some weird exception.

I read some questions related to `C++11` threads and I realized that, I also need to use `-pthread` flag to compile the code properly. Using `-pthread` worked fine and I was able to run the threaded code.

My question is, whether the `C++11` multi-threading model uses `Pthreads` in the background?
Or is it written from the scratch?

I don't know if any of the members are `gcc` contributors but I am just curious.

Comment: @Kay it looks like the question is about g++ 4.6.

Comment: The "some weird exception" is probably `std::system_error`, required by the standard when threads cannot be created (e.g. because you haven't linked to libpthread.so with `-pthread`).  I am working on improving the message that exception gives, see http://gcc.gnu.org/PR52681

Comment: @JonathanWakely....Yes, this is the exception that I am dealing with on my Linux machine...with AMD Turion X2....While it went smoothly without `-pthread` flag on my roommates Intel machine...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you run `g++ -v` it will give you a bunch of information about how it was configured.  One of those things will generally be a line that looks like

```
Thread model: posix
```

which means that it was configured to use pthreads for its threading library (std::thread in libstdc++), and which means you also need to use any flags that might be required for pthreads on your system (`-pthread` on Linux).

This has nothing specific to do with the standard, its just a detail of how the standard is implemented by g++

Comment: N.B. one of those things will _always_ be that line, if thread support is absent it will say "Thread model: single"

Comment: Note that the GCC reported thread model also reflects on other parts of GCC, like libgcc, and the compiler itself. Many things may be built on top of that threads implementation, not all equally obvious. GCC is quite "monolithic" in that regard...

Answer (score 9):

C++ doesn't specify how threads are implemented. In practice C++ threads are generally implemented as thin wrappers over pre-existing system thread libraries (like pthreads or windows threads). There is even a provision to access the underlying thread object with std::thread::native_handle().

Comment: G++ is not a unix compiler, it works on Windows too, where it can be configured to use either pthread-win32 or native Windows threads. So far noone has done the work for GCC to make its C++11 thread library work with Windows threads, I posted some ideas to http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-05/msg00020.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it crashes is that if you do not specify `-pthreads` or `-lpthreads`, a number of weakly defined pthreads stub functions from `libc` are linked. These stub functions are enough to get your program to link without error. However, actually creating a pthread requires the full on libpthread.a library, and when the dynamic linker (`dl`) tries to resolve those missing functions, you get a segmentation violation.