# C++11 Thread not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11

My programs looks like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <exception>

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!!!!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "In Main\n";
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using the following command I get no errors

```
g++-4.7 -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

But when I run it I get the following error

```
In Main
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could someone help me with where I am going wrong?

Comment: it most probably won't be the root cause of the error message you see, but std::cout (and others) are not supposed to be used concurrently without access serialization

Comment: @bobah - there's no concurrent use here. The insertion in `main()` finished before the thread is created.

Comment: @PeteBecker - that's precisely why I said "most probably won't be"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I use C++11 threads with GCC, i use:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -pthread -g main.cpp
```

That works for me.

Comment: But why do we have to include -pthread when <thread> is available in the std library???

Comment: GCC doesn't automatically include the pthread library yet. They said it will be fixed in a later version.

Comment: would you have a link to where they have mentioned that. Would like to read that article

Comment: I can't remember where I read that. So, I guess I failed the Citation Needed test.

Answer (score 6):

When compiling your code with `g++`, use the `-pthread` option.

Below is the answer I find from stackoverflow:
[In g++ is C++ 11 thread model using pthreads in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784153/in-g-is-c-11-thread-model-using-pthreads-in-the-background)

Answer (score 3):

Everybody already answered that you need the -pthread argument passed to the compiler. Almost for sure it won't change in 4.8 but according to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52681 the exception will at least have a nice message stating what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to link against the pthread library

Answer (score 0):

You can try with,

```
g++ --std=c++11 -lpthread main.cpp
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What's the difference and why does it provide a solution?